# Random.choice same result

Tags: python, random

I'm using Python and its standard library function `random.choice`. I'm just wondering, is there a way to not get the same result, for example not getting `"Strawberry"` twice. I have tried  loads of ways but came up with nothing.

I have included my code:

```
#Random selection for for doughnuts
import random
from tkinter import *

Doughnuts = ['Strawberry', 'Apple Cinnamon',
             'Blueberry Blaster', 'Custard', 'Sugar', ...]

def RandomDough():
    for i in range(6):
        print (random.choice(Doughnuts))

app=Tk()
app.title('Your tkinter app')
app.geometry('450x100+200+100')
b1=Button(app, text='Random Special', width = 20, command=RandomDough)
b1.pack(side='right')
app.mainloop()
```

I even tried using `random.sample` but I couldn't think how to convert the `int` numbers to the actual word aka `"Strawberry"`:

```
#Random selection for for doughnuts
import random
from tkinter import *

def RandomDough():
    Doughnuts = random.sample(range(1, 8), 6)
    print (Doughnuts)

app=Tk()
app.title('Your tkinter app')
app.geometry('700x200+200+100')
b1=Button(app,text='Random Special',width = 20,height = 20,command=RandomDough)
b1.pack(side ='right')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: there is more doughnut flavours but for some reason it wouldnt allow me add them in due to not going over the 4 spaces

Comment: Your question is extremely confusing. Why isn't, for example, `random.sample(Doughnuts, 4)` what you want?

Comment: `random.sample(Doughnuts, 6)`?

Answer (score 5):

Just pass the `Doughnuts` *list* to `random.sample()`; don't use indices:

```
Doughnuts = ['Strawberry ','Apple Cinnamon ','Blueberry Blaster ','Custard ','Sugar']
for choice in random.sample(Doughnuts, 6):
    print(choice)
```

Answer (score 3):

Shuffle them, then use or iterate over a slice...:

```
from random import shuffle

Doughnuts = ['Strawberry ','Apple Cinnamon ','Blueberry Blaster ','Custard ','Sugar']
shuffle(Doughnuts)
for doughnut in Doughnuts[:6]:
    print doughnut # or whatever
```

This can be adapted to pick unique dougnuts one at a time, eg:

```
shuffle(Doughnuts)
items = iter(Doughnuts)
doughnut = next(items) # get 1
# .... other code
another_doughnut = next(items)
```

Comment: `random.sample()` would have done just fine here if all they wanted was 6 items. Randomizing the whole list should only be done if you you then need multiple 'samples' that are all unique.